# Tips to find the minimum period of an exponential congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have to find the minimum period of this congruence: $2^x \equiv 8\;(11)$
$$
2^1 \equiv2,\;2^2 \equiv4,\;2^3 \equiv8,\;2^4 \equiv5,\;2^5 \equiv-1,\; 2^{10} \equiv1
$$

My question is: how do I know that it is not necessary to calculate the congurences from $2^6$ to $2^9$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know by Fermat's little theorem that the period has to divide $10$, since $11$ is a prime. Since you worked out that $2^5\not\equiv1\bmod10$, this shows that the period cannot be strictly less than $10$, so it *is* $10$.

Comment: So in general, if the module $p$ is prime, do I have to see only the exponents that divide $p-1$?

For example: $4^x\equiv3\;(13)$
$$p -1 = 12 \rightarrow1,2,3,4,6,12|12$$
$$
4^1 \equiv4,\;4^2 \equiv3,\; 4^3 \equiv-1,\;4^4 \equiv9,\;4^6 \equiv1,\;
$$

Comment: @Shyvert Yes. This is just a special case of Lagrange's theorem on $\mathbb Z^×$.